# How to do ups = ups+1 after a action have been sent from client?

Tags: tastypie

I want to send a action from client to do
ups = ups +1 in server

the  ups  = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_(u'vote count'), default=0)

How i to do these?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a resource with only post allowed. Then every time you receive a post request do 'ups +=1'

The other way is to use an update on a resource, probably best with the 'patch' request.